# ExpectedObjects compares concrete objects instead of only interfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I have an xUnit unit test project utilizing [ExpectedObjects](https://github.com/derekgreer/expectedObjects). Right now I'm trying to test a service that returns objects conforming to an interface. For the sake of the question let's take an example interface

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and two different implementations:

```
public class ComplexEntity : INamed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    /* Many other properties follow... */
}
```

```
public class SimpleEntity : INamed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The method under test has a signature of

```
public IEnumerable<INamed> GetNames();
```

All that I care about is that the correct names are returned. So after mocking whatever dependencies the service might take I construct an expected result set as follows:

```
IEnumerable<INamed> expected = new []
{
    new SimpleEntity { Name = "NAM1" },
    new SimpleEntity { Name = "NAM2" },
    ...
}
```

And I compare them as follows:

```
// ACT
var result = systemUnderTest.GetNames();

// ASSERT
expected.ToExpectedObject().ShouldMatch(result);
```

This will fail. The collection that is actually returned by the `GetNames` under test is a mixed collection of both `SimpleEntities` and `ComplexEntities`, and none will match, because the `Id` properties of returned objects are non-zero, and other properties from `ComplexEntity` that I don't care about are not even present in the `expected` set.

The ExpectedObjects docs give me no guidance on this. The `ShouldMatch` is supposed to work on anonymous types, so this should (and does) work:

```
expected.Select(e => new { e.Name }).ToExpectedObject().ShouldMatch(result);
```

But I see this as an inflexible workaround. There are many other methods with contracts including only interfaces where I don't care about the underlying types. I would have to manually select the same properties from an interface in every such test and if that interface ever changed to include more properties *the tests would still pass even though they wouldn't be correctly checking the contract*. For example if I added the `Id` property to `INamed`, the test would still pass and would never even test for `Id`, allowing errors to go on silently.

Is there an out-of-the-box way to make ExpectedObjects compare only the public interfaces? I guess I could manually write a contrived, dynamic method creating an anonymous type out of an interface, make it generic and roll with it, something with usage like:

```
expected.ToExpectedObject().ShouldMatchInterface<INamed>(result);
```

but that makes me question using the library in the first place, as the effort put into `ShouldMatchInterface` would probably be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're setting up the Expected Object correctly.

For example, with a `GetNames()` implementation like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<INamed> GetNames()
    {
        return new[] {
            new ComplexEntity() { Id = 1, Name = "NAM1", Domain = "DOM1" },
            new ComplexEntity() { Id = 2, Name = "NAM2", Domain = "DOM2" }
        };
    }
}
```

The following xUnit + ExpectedObjects test will pass:

```cs
using ConsoleProject;
using ExpectedObjects;
using Xunit;

namespace ConsoleProject_Tests
{
    public class ExpectedObjectsTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void GetNames_should_return_INamed_ExpectedObjects_Style()
        {
            var expected = new[]
            {
                new { Name = "NAM1" },
                new { Name = "NAM2" }
            }.ToExpectedObject();

            var systemUnderTest = new Foo();
            var actual = systemUnderTest.GetNames();

            expected.ShouldMatch(actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `ToExpectedObject()` is being fed anonymous objects, not concrete classes.

Now compare that with the old way of doing things by implementing a custom `IEqualityComparer<INamed>` which just happens to be on the test class...

```cs
using ConsoleProject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;

namespace ConsoleProject_Tests
{
    public class ClassicXUnitTests : IEqualityComparer<INamed>
    {
        bool IEqualityComparer<INamed>.Equals(INamed x, INamed y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null) return true;
            if (x == null || y == null) return false;
            return String.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<INamed>.GetHashCode(INamed obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void GetNames_should_return_INamed_xUnit_Style()
        {
            var expected = new[]
            {
                new SimpleEntity() { Name = "NAM1" },
                new SimpleEntity() { Name = "NAM2" }
            };

            var systemUnderTest = new Foo();
            var actual = systemUnderTest.GetNames();

            Assert.Equal<INamed>(expected, actual, this);
        }
    }
}
```

It still needs a concrete class that implements `INamed` because you can't just create a new abstract class or interface.

Comment: So basically you're saying that the `expected` part of any test should _always_ be an anonymous type?

Comment: Not always, no. For strongly typed collections you would use concrete classes as per [Strongly Typed Comparisons](https://github.com/derekgreer/expectedObjects/wiki/Strongly-Typed-Comparisons). For interface-driven collections you use anonymous objects as per [Partial Comparisons](https://github.com/derekgreer/expectedObjects/wiki/Partial-Comparisons). Using anonymous objects also gives you access to [Custom Comparisons](https://github.com/derekgreer/expectedObjects/wiki/Custom-Comparisons) where you could do things like `var expected = new { Name = Expect.NotNull() }.ToExpectedObject();`